# Cannot make a successful POST Call to Express App on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, http-status-code-401

I have 2 separate applications currently deployed to Heroku: a Node/Express and a UI app (Angular).  I cannot make a certain POST call successfully from my UI app in the deployed environment.  I get a 401 Unauthorized error.  However, I can make the same POST call successfully from my UI app on my local to the deployed Express app on Heroku.  Similarly and obviously, when both are running on local I get no errors.

It's not a CORS error because the feature page loads properly.  The feature page is a login screen, but I'm just sending the login credentials as an object to the API endpoint; there is no token involved yet.

Any ideas? Is there something in Heroku config for my API app that I have to change?